# Python built-in base-256 to base-10 conversion and vice versa?

Tags: python

I want to store large numbers (200-300 digits +) in a text file, so I want to know if there is either a built-in function that converts base-10 numbers to base-256 equivalents and vice versa in Python, or whether there is a module that supports this (much like the default hex() function).

Comment: Is there a standard for base 256? What are the 256 symbols used to represent digits?

Comment: @Denziloe then there is this - https://github.com/Parkayun/base65536

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998605/efficient-binary-to-string-formatting-like-base64-but-for-utf8-utf16 (which is also almost directly related to the project linked to by @DeepSpace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Base256' is essentially binary bytes.  While one can interpret the result as latin-1 encoded text, that does not seem as much use.  So I would not suffix the resulting file as .txt.

That aside, the `struct` module us used to convert data to and from bytes. A relatively simple example:

```
>>> import struct
>>> b = struct.pack('HhL', 33333, -33, 3333333333)
>>> b
b'5\x82\xdf\xffU\xa1\xae\xc6'
>>> struct.unpack('HhL', b)
(33333, -33, 3333333333)
```

When writing to or reading from a file, remember to open in binary mode.

Answer (score 3):

Integers have the [`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)-method:

```
base256 = number.to_bytes((number.bit_length()+7)//8, 'big')

number =int.from_bytes(base256, 'big')
```

Comment: You can't store multiple numbers in a file like this because you wouldn't know the length when you read them.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is only available in Python 3.

Comment: it is easy to prefix such a numbers with a fixed amount of bytes for length using the other address.